# Recurrence relation in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a DataFrame, `df`, in pandas with series `df.A` and `df.B` and am trying to create a third series, `df.C` that is dependent on A and B as well as the previous result. That is:

`C[0]=A[0]`

`C[n]=A[n] + B[n]*C[n-1]`

what is the most efficient way of doing this? Ideally, I wouldn't have to fall back to a `for` loop.

---

**Edit**

This is the desired output for C given A and B. Now just need to figure out how...

```
import pandas as pd

a = [ 2, 3,-8,-2, 1]
b = [ 1, 1, 4, 2, 1]
c = [ 2, 5,12,22,23]

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': a, 'B': b, 'C': c})
df
```

Comment: Can you add a small reproducible sample data set and your desired data set? Is it about financial mathematics?

Comment: @MaxU yes and yes. thanks

Comment: there are [a few function for financial math, provided by numpy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/routines.financial.html) - you might want to check them. What kind of financial instrument are you asking about? Is it something like fixed-rate mortgage? If yes, it would make sense to create a bit more realistic sample data set...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can vectorize this with obnoxious cumulative products and zipping together of other vectors.  But it won't end up saving you time.  As a matter of fact, it will likely be numerically unstable.

Instead, you can use `numba` to speed up your loop.

```
from numba import njit
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

@njit
def dynamic_alpha(a, b):
    c = a.copy()
    for i in range(1, len(a)):
        c[i] = a[i] + b[i] * c[i - 1]
    return c

df.assign(C=dynamic_alpha(df.A.values, df.B.values))

   A  B   C
0  2  1   2
1  3  1   5
2 -8  4  12
3 -2  2  22
4  1  1  23
```

---

For this simple calculation, this will be about as fast as a simple

```
df.assign(C=np.arange(len(df)) ** 2 + 2)
```

---

```
df = pd.concat([df] * 10000)
%timeit df.assign(C=dynamic_alpha(df.A.values, df.B.values))
%timeit df.assign(C=np.arange(len(df)) ** 2 + 2)
```

---

> ```
> 337 µs ± 5.87 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
> 333 µs ± 20.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
> ```

Answer (score -1):

try this:

`C[0]=A[0]
C=[A[i]+B[i]*C[i-1] for i in range(1,len(A))]`

very much quicker than a loop.